# "ambiguous symbol error" while building a C++/Tcl program using boost library 

Tags: c++, boost

I have gone through the guides given out here &  http://cpptcl.sourceforge.net/doc/compiling.html Hence I have pretty much done the basic stuffs.

Here's the code for Hello.cc given in the guide present in C++/Tcl:

```
#include "cpptcl.h" 
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

void hello()
{
     cout << "Hello C++/Tcl!" << endl;
}

CPPTCL_MODULE(Mymodule, i)
{
     i.def("hello", hello);
}
```

According to the guide, we need cpptcl.h & cpptcl.cc & few other files in details/ directory which I have included.

While building the code, it's giving me the following error:

```
1>Compiling...
1>cpptcl.cc
cpptcl.cc(35) : warning C4800: 'int' : forcing value to bool 'true' or 'false' (performance warning)
cpptcl.cc(325) : error C2039: 'what' : is not a member of 'boost::exception'
1>        c:\program files\boost\boost_1_44_0\boost\exception\exception.hpp(194) : see declaration of 'boost::exception'
1>cpptcl.cc(366) : error C2872: 'exception' : ambiguous symbol
1>        could be 'c:\program files\boost\boost_1_44_0\boost\exception\exception.hpp(194) : boost::exception'
1>        or 'c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 8\vc\include\exception(88) : std::exception'
1>cpptcl.cc(368) : error C2039: 'what' : is not a member of 'boost::exception'
1>c:\program files\boost\boost_1_44_0\boost\exception\exception.hpp(194) : see declaration of 'boost::exception'
1>3 error(s), 2 warning(s)
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

It's not able to resolve exception symbol. I am not sure whether the exception.hpp or the std::exception.

Below is the code for cpptcl.cc

```
 //
// Copyright (C) 2004-2005, Maciej Sobczak
//
// Permission to copy, use, modify, sell and distribute this software
// is granted provided this copyright notice appears in all copies.
// This software is provided "as is" without express or implied
// warranty, and with no claim as to its suitability for any purpose.
//

#include "cpptcl.h"
#include 
#include 
#include 
#include 

using namespace Tcl;
using namespace Tcl::details;
using namespace std;
using namespace boost;


result::result(Tcl_Interp *interp) : interp_(interp) {}

result::operator bool() const
{
     Tcl_Obj *obj = Tcl_GetObjResult(interp_);

     int val, cc;
     cc = Tcl_GetBooleanFromObj(interp_, obj, &val);
     if (cc != TCL_OK)
     {
          throw tcl_error(interp_);
     }

     return static_cast(val);
}

result::operator double() const
{
     Tcl_Obj *obj = Tcl_GetObjResult(interp_);

     double val;
     int cc = Tcl_GetDoubleFromObj(interp_, obj, &val);
     if (cc != TCL_OK)
     {
          throw tcl_error(interp_);
     }

     return val;
}

result::operator int() const
{
     Tcl_Obj *obj = Tcl_GetObjResult(interp_);

     int val, cc;
     cc = Tcl_GetIntFromObj(interp_, obj, &val);
     if (cc != TCL_OK)
     {
          throw tcl_error(interp_);
     }

     return val;
}

result::operator long() const
{
     Tcl_Obj *obj = Tcl_GetObjResult(interp_);

     long val;
     int cc;
     cc = Tcl_GetLongFromObj(interp_, obj, &val);
     if (cc != TCL_OK)
     {
          throw tcl_error(interp_);
     }

     return val;
}

result::operator string() const
{
     Tcl_Obj *obj = Tcl_GetObjResult(interp_);
     return Tcl_GetString(obj);
}

result::operator object() const
{
     return object(Tcl_GetObjResult(interp_));
}


void details::set_result(Tcl_Interp *interp, bool b)
{
     Tcl_SetObjResult(interp, Tcl_NewBooleanObj(b));
}

void details::set_result(Tcl_Interp *interp, int i)
{
     Tcl_SetObjResult(interp, Tcl_NewIntObj(i));
}

void details::set_result(Tcl_Interp *interp, long i)
{
     Tcl_SetObjResult(interp, Tcl_NewLongObj(i));
}

void details::set_result(Tcl_Interp *interp, double d)
{
     Tcl_SetObjResult(interp, Tcl_NewDoubleObj(d));
}

void details::set_result(Tcl_Interp *interp, string const &s)
{
     Tcl_SetObjResult(interp,
          Tcl_NewStringObj(s.data(), static_cast(s.size())));
}

void details::set_result(Tcl_Interp *interp, void *p)
{
     ostringstream ss;
     ss (s.size())));
}

void details::set_result(Tcl_Interp *interp, object const &o)
{
     Tcl_SetObjResult(interp, o.get_object());
}


void details::check_params_no(int objc, int required)
{
     if (objc  > callback_interp_map;
typedef map callback_map;

callback_map callbacks;
callback_map constructors;

// map of call policies
typedef map policies_interp_map;
typedef map policies_map;

policies_map call_policies;

// map of object handlers
typedef map > class_interp_map;
typedef map class_handlers_map;

class_handlers_map class_handlers;


// helper for finding call policies - returns true when found
bool find_policies(Tcl_Interp *interp, string const &cmdName,
     policies_interp_map::iterator &piti)
{
     policies_map::iterator pit = call_policies.find(interp);
     if (pit == call_policies.end())
     {
          return false;
     }

     piti = pit->second.find(cmdName);
     return piti != pit->second.end();
}

extern "C"
int object_handler(ClientData cd, Tcl_Interp *interp,
     int objc, Tcl_Obj * CONST objv[]);

// helper function for post-processing call policies
// for both free functions (isMethod == false)
// and class methods (isMethod == true)
void post_process_policies(Tcl_Interp *interp, policies &pol,
     Tcl_Obj * CONST objv[], bool isMethod)
{
     // check if it is a factory
     if (!pol.factory_.empty())
     {
          class_handlers_map::iterator it = class_handlers.find(interp);
          if (it == class_handlers.end())
          {
               throw tcl_error(
                    "Factory was registered for unknown class.");
          }

          class_interp_map::iterator oit = it->second.find(pol.factory_);
          if (oit == it->second.end())
          {
               throw tcl_error(
                    "Factory was registered for unknown class.");
          }

          class_handler_base *chb = oit->second.get();

          // register a new command for the object returned
          // by this factory function
          // if everything went OK, the result is the address of the
          // new object in the 'pXXX' form
          // - the new command will be created with this name

          Tcl_CreateObjCommand(interp,
               Tcl_GetString(Tcl_GetObjResult(interp)),
               object_handler, static_cast(chb), 0);
     }

     // process all declared sinks
     // - unregister all object commands that envelopes the pointers
     for (vector::iterator s = pol.sinks_.begin();
          s != pol.sinks_.end(); ++s)
     {
          if (isMethod == false)
          {
               // example: if there is a declared sink at parameter 3,
               // and the Tcl command was:
               // % fun par1 par2 PAR3 par4
               // then the index 3 correctly points into the objv array

               int index = *s;
               Tcl_DeleteCommand(interp, Tcl_GetString(objv[index]));
          }
          else
          {
               // example: if there is a declared sink at parameter 3,
               // and the Tcl command was:
               // % $p method par1 par2 PAR3 par4
               // then the index 3 needs to be incremented
               // in order correctly point into the 4th index of objv array

               int index = *s + 1;
               Tcl_DeleteCommand(interp, Tcl_GetString(objv[index]));
          }
     }
}

// actual functions handling various callbacks

// generic callback handler
extern "C"
int callback_handler(ClientData cd, Tcl_Interp *interp,
     int objc, Tcl_Obj * CONST objv[])
{
     callback_map::iterator it = callbacks.find(interp);
     if (it == callbacks.end())
     {
          Tcl_SetResult(interp,
               "Trying to invoke non-existent callback (wrong interpreter?)",
               TCL_STATIC);
          return TCL_ERROR;
     }

     string cmdName(Tcl_GetString(objv[0]));
     callback_interp_map::iterator iti = it->second.find(cmdName);
     if (iti == it->second.end())
     {
          Tcl_SetResult(interp,
               "Trying to invoke non-existent callback (wrong cmd name?)",
               TCL_STATIC);
          return TCL_ERROR;
     }

     policies_map::iterator pit = call_policies.find(interp);
     if (pit == call_policies.end())
     {
          Tcl_SetResult(interp,
               "Trying to invoke callback with no known policies",
               TCL_STATIC);
          return TCL_ERROR;
     }

     policies_interp_map::iterator piti;
     if (find_policies(interp, cmdName, piti) == false)
     {
          Tcl_SetResult(interp,
               "Trying to invoke callback with no known policies",
               TCL_STATIC);
          return TCL_ERROR;
     }

     policies &pol = piti->second;

     try
     {
          iti->second->invoke(interp, objc, objv, pol);

          post_process_policies(interp, pol, objv, false);
     }
     catch (boost::exception const &e)
     {
          Tcl_SetResult(interp, const_cast(e.what()), TCL_VOLATILE);
          return TCL_ERROR;
     }
     catch (...)
     {
          Tcl_SetResult(interp, "Unknown error.", TCL_STATIC);
          return TCL_ERROR;
     }

     return TCL_OK;
}

// generic "object" command handler
extern "C"
int object_handler(ClientData cd, Tcl_Interp *interp,
     int objc, Tcl_Obj * CONST objv[])
{
     // here, client data points to the singleton object
     // which is responsible for managing commands for
     // objects of a given type

     class_handler_base *chb = reinterpret_cast(cd);

     // the command name has the form 'pXXX' where XXX is the address
     // of the "this" object

     string const str(Tcl_GetString(objv[0]));
     istringstream ss(str);
     char dummy;
     void *p;
     ss >> dummy >> p;

     try
     {
          string methodName(Tcl_GetString(objv[1]));
          policies &pol = chb->get_policies(methodName);

          chb->invoke(p, interp, objc, objv, pol);

          post_process_policies(interp, pol, objv, true);
     }
     catch (exception const &e)
     {
          Tcl_SetResult(interp, const_cast(e.what()), TCL_VOLATILE);
          return TCL_ERROR;
     }
     catch (...)
     {
          Tcl_SetResult(interp, "Unknown error.", TCL_STATIC);
          return TCL_ERROR;
     }

     return TCL_OK;
}

// generic "constructor" command
extern "C"
int constructor_handler(ClientData cd, Tcl_Interp *interp,
     int objc, Tcl_Obj * CONST objv[])
{
     // here, client data points to the singleton object
     // which is responsible for managing commands for
     // objects of a given type

     class_handler_base *chb = reinterpret_cast(cd);

     callback_map::iterator it = constructors.find(interp);
     if (it == constructors.end())
     {
          Tcl_SetResult(interp,
               "Trying to invoke non-existent callback (wrong interpreter?)",
               TCL_STATIC);
          return TCL_ERROR;
     }

     string className(Tcl_GetString(objv[0]));
     callback_interp_map::iterator iti = it->second.find(className);
     if (iti == it->second.end())
     {
          Tcl_SetResult(interp,
               "Trying to invoke non-existent callback (wrong class name?)",
               TCL_STATIC);
          return TCL_ERROR;
     }

     policies_interp_map::iterator piti;
     if (find_policies(interp, className, piti) == false)
     {
          Tcl_SetResult(interp,
               "Trying to invoke callback with no known policies",
               TCL_STATIC);
          return TCL_ERROR;
     }

     policies &pol = piti->second;

     try
     {
          iti->second->invoke(interp, objc, objv, pol);

          // if everything went OK, the result is the address of the
          // new object in the 'pXXX' form
          // - we can create a new command with this name

          Tcl_CreateObjCommand(interp,
               Tcl_GetString(Tcl_GetObjResult(interp)),
               object_handler, static_cast(chb), 0);
     }
     catch (std::exception const &e)
     {
          Tcl_SetResult(interp, const_cast(e.what()), TCL_VOLATILE);
          return TCL_ERROR;
     }
     catch (...)
     {
          Tcl_SetResult(interp, "Unknown error.", TCL_STATIC);
          return TCL_ERROR;
     }

     return TCL_OK;
}

} // namespace anonymous

Tcl::details::no_init_type Tcl::no_init;


policies & policies::factory(string const &name)
{
     factory_ = name;
     return *this;
}

policies & policies::sink(int index)
{
     sinks_.push_back(index);
     return *this;
}

policies & policies::variadic()
{
     variadic_ = true;
     return *this;
}

policies Tcl::factory(string const &name)
{
     return policies().factory(name);
}

policies Tcl::sink(int index)
{
     return policies().sink(index);
}

policies Tcl::variadic()
{
     return policies().variadic();
}


class_handler_base::class_handler_base()
{
     // default policies for the -delete command
     policies_["-delete"] = policies();
}

void class_handler_base::register_method(string const &name,
     shared_ptr ocb, policies const &p)
{
     methods_[name] = ocb;
     policies_[name] = p;
}

policies & class_handler_base::get_policies(string const &name)
{
     policies_map_type::iterator it = policies_.find(name);
     if (it == policies_.end())
     {
          throw tcl_error("Trying to use non-existent policy: " + name);
     }

     return it->second;
}


object::object()
     : interp_(0)
{
     obj_ = Tcl_NewObj();
     Tcl_IncrRefCount(obj_);
}

object::object(bool b)
     : interp_(0)
{
     obj_ = Tcl_NewBooleanObj(b);
     Tcl_IncrRefCount(obj_);
}

object::object(char const *buf, size_t size)
     : interp_(0)
{
     obj_ = Tcl_NewByteArrayObj(
          reinterpret_cast(buf),
          static_cast(size));
     Tcl_IncrRefCount(obj_);
}

object::object(double d)
     : interp_(0)
{
     obj_ = Tcl_NewDoubleObj(d);
     Tcl_IncrRefCount(obj_);
}

object::object(int i)
     : interp_(0)
{
     obj_ = Tcl_NewIntObj(i);
     Tcl_IncrRefCount(obj_);
}

object::object(long l)
     : interp_(0)
{
     obj_ = Tcl_NewLongObj(l);
     Tcl_IncrRefCount(obj_);
}

object::object(char const *s)
     : interp_(0)
{
     obj_ = Tcl_NewStringObj(s, -1);
     Tcl_IncrRefCount(obj_);
}

object::object(string const &s)
     : interp_(0)
{
     obj_ = Tcl_NewStringObj(s.data(), static_cast(s.size()));
     Tcl_IncrRefCount(obj_);
}

object::object(Tcl_Obj *o, bool shared)
     : interp_(0)
{
     init(o, shared);
}

object::object(object const &other, bool shared)
     : interp_(other.get_interp())
{
     init(other.obj_, shared);
}

void object::init(Tcl_Obj *o, bool shared)
{
     if (shared)
     {
          obj_ = o;
     }
     else
     {
          obj_ = Tcl_DuplicateObj(o);
     }
     Tcl_IncrRefCount(obj_);
}

object::~object()
{
     Tcl_DecrRefCount(obj_);
}

object & object::assign(bool b)
{
     Tcl_SetBooleanObj(obj_, b);
     return *this;
}

object & object::resize(size_t size)
{
     Tcl_SetByteArrayLength(obj_, static_cast(size));
     return *this;
}

object & object::assign(char const *buf, size_t size)
{
     Tcl_SetByteArrayObj(obj_,
          reinterpret_cast(buf),
          static_cast(size));
     return *this;
}

object & object::assign(double d)
{
     Tcl_SetDoubleObj(obj_, d);
     return *this;
}

object & object::assign(int i)
{
     Tcl_SetIntObj(obj_, i);
     return *this;
}

object & object::assign(long l)
{
     Tcl_SetLongObj(obj_, l);
     return *this;
}

object & object::assign(char const *s)
{
     Tcl_SetStringObj(obj_, s, -1);
     return *this;
}

object & object::assign(string const &s)
{
     Tcl_SetStringObj(obj_, s.data(), static_cast(s.size()));
     return *this;
}

object & object::assign(object const &other)
{
     object(other).swap(*this);
     return *this;
}

object & object::assign(Tcl_Obj *o)
{
     object(o).swap(*this);
     return *this;
}

object & object::swap(object &other)
{
     std::swap(obj_, other.obj_);
     std::swap(interp_, other.interp_);
     return *this;
}

template 
bool object::get(interpreter &i) const
{
     int retVal;
     int res = Tcl_GetBooleanFromObj(i.get(), obj_, &retVal);
     if (res != TCL_OK)
     {
          throw tcl_error(i.get());
     }

     return static_cast(retVal);
}

template 
vector object::get >(interpreter &) const
{
     size_t size;
     char const *buf = get(size);
     return vector(buf, buf + size);
}

template 
double object::get(interpreter &i) const
{
     double retVal;
     int res = Tcl_GetDoubleFromObj(i.get(), obj_, &retVal);
     if (res != TCL_OK)
     {
          throw tcl_error(i.get());
     }

     return retVal;
}

template 
int object::get(interpreter &i) const
{
     int retVal;

     int res = Tcl_GetIntFromObj(i.get(), obj_, &retVal);
     if (res != TCL_OK)
     {
          throw tcl_error(i.get());
     }

     return retVal;
}

template 
long object::get(interpreter &i) const
{
     long retVal;
     int res = Tcl_GetLongFromObj(i.get(), obj_, &retVal);
     if (res != TCL_OK)
     {
          throw tcl_error(i.get());
     }

     return retVal;
}

template 
char const * object::get(interpreter &) const
{
     return get();
}

template 
string object::get(interpreter &) const
{
     int len;
     char const *buf = Tcl_GetStringFromObj(obj_, &len);
     return string(buf, buf + len);
}

char const * object::get() const
{
     return Tcl_GetString(obj_);
}

char const * object::get(size_t &size) const
{
     int len;
     unsigned char *buf = Tcl_GetByteArrayFromObj(obj_, &len);
     size = len;
     return const_cast(reinterpret_cast(buf));
}

size_t object::length(interpreter &i) const
{
     int len;
     int res = Tcl_ListObjLength(i.get(), obj_, &len);

     if (res != TCL_OK)
     {
          throw tcl_error(i.get());
     }

     return static_cast(len);
}

object object::at(interpreter &i, size_t index) const
{
     Tcl_Obj *o;
     int res = Tcl_ListObjIndex(i.get(), obj_, static_cast(index), &o);
     if (res != TCL_OK)
     {
          throw tcl_error(i.get());
     }
     if (o == NULL)
     {
          throw tcl_error("Index out of range.");
     }

     return object(o);
}

object & object::append(interpreter &i, object const &o)
{
     int res = Tcl_ListObjAppendElement(i.get(), obj_, o.obj_);
     if (res != TCL_OK)
     {
          throw tcl_error(i.get());
     }

     return *this;
}

object & object::append_list(interpreter &i, object const &o)
{
     int res = Tcl_ListObjAppendList(i.get(), obj_, o.obj_);
     if (res != TCL_OK)
     {
          throw tcl_error(i.get());
     }

     return *this;
}

object & object::replace(interpreter &i, size_t index, size_t count,
     object const &o)
{
     int res = Tcl_ListObjReplace(i.get(), obj_,
          static_cast(index), static_cast(count),
          1, &(o.obj_));
     if (res != TCL_OK)
     {
          throw tcl_error(i.get());
     }

     return *this;
}

object & object::replace_list(interpreter &i, size_t index, size_t count,
     object const &o)
{
     int objc;
     Tcl_Obj **objv;

     int res = Tcl_ListObjGetElements(i.get(), obj_, &objc, &objv);
     if (res != TCL_OK)
     {
          throw tcl_error(i.get());
     }

     res = Tcl_ListObjReplace(i.get(), obj_,
          static_cast(index), static_cast(count),
          objc, objv);
     if (res != TCL_OK)
     {
          throw tcl_error(i.get());
     }

     return *this;
}

void object::set_interp(Tcl_Interp *interp)
{
     interp_ = interp;
}

Tcl_Interp * object::get_interp() const
{
     return interp_;
}


interpreter::interpreter()
{
     interp_ =  Tcl_CreateInterp();
}

interpreter::interpreter(Tcl_Interp *interp, bool owner)
{
     interp_ =  interp;
     owner_ = owner;
}

interpreter::~interpreter()
{
     if (owner_)
     {
          // clear all callback info belonging to this interpreter
          clear_definitions(interp_);

          Tcl_DeleteInterp(interp_);
     }
}

void interpreter::make_safe()
{
     int cc = Tcl_MakeSafe(interp_);
     if (cc != TCL_OK)
     {
          throw tcl_error(interp_);
     }
}

result interpreter::eval(string const &script)
{
     int cc = Tcl_Eval(interp_, script.c_str());
     if (cc != TCL_OK)
     {
          throw tcl_error(interp_);
     }

     return result(interp_);
}

result interpreter::eval(istream &s)
{
     string str(
          istreambuf_iterator(s.rdbuf()),
          istreambuf_iterator()
     );
     return eval(str);
}

result interpreter::eval(object const &o)
{
     int cc = Tcl_EvalObjEx(interp_, o.get_object(), 0);
     if (cc != TCL_OK)
     {
          throw tcl_error(interp_);
     }

     return result(interp_);
}

void interpreter::pkg_provide(string const &name, string const &version)
{
     int cc = Tcl_PkgProvide(interp_, name.c_str(), version.c_str());
     if (cc != TCL_OK)
     {
          throw tcl_error(interp_);
     }
}

void interpreter::create_alias(string const &cmd,
     interpreter &targetInterp, string const &targetCmd)
{
     int cc = Tcl_CreateAlias(interp_, cmd.c_str(),
          targetInterp.interp_, targetCmd.c_str(), 0, 0);
     if (cc != TCL_OK)
     {
          throw tcl_error(interp_);
     }
}

void interpreter::clear_definitions(Tcl_Interp *interp)
{
     // delete all callbacks that were registered for given interpreter

     {
          callback_map::iterator it = callbacks.find(interp);
          if (it == callbacks.end())
          {
               // no callbacks defined for this interpreter
               return;
          }

          callback_interp_map &imap = it->second;
          for (callback_interp_map::iterator it2 = imap.begin();
               it2 != imap.end(); ++it2)
          {
               Tcl_DeleteCommand(interp, it2->first.c_str());
          }

          callbacks.erase(interp);
     }

     // delete all constructors

     {
          callback_map::iterator it = constructors.find(interp);
          if (it == constructors.end())
          {
               // no callbacks defined for this interpreter
               return;
          }

          callback_interp_map &imap = it->second;
          for (callback_interp_map::iterator it2 = imap.begin();
               it2 != imap.end(); ++it2)
          {
               Tcl_DeleteCommand(interp, it2->first.c_str());
          }

          callbacks.erase(interp);
     }

     // delete all call policies

     call_policies.erase(interp);

     // delete all object handlers
     // (we have to assume that all living objects were destroyed,
     // otherwise Bad Things will happen)

     class_handlers.erase(interp);
}

void interpreter::add_function(string const &name,
     shared_ptr cb, policies const &p)
{
     Tcl_CreateObjCommand(interp_, name.c_str(),
          callback_handler, 0, 0);

     callbacks[interp_][name] = cb;
     call_policies[interp_][name] = p;
}

void interpreter::add_class(string const &name,
     shared_ptr chb)
{
     class_handlers[interp_][name] = chb;
}

void interpreter::add_constructor(string const &name,
     shared_ptr chb, shared_ptr cb,
     policies const &p)
{
     Tcl_CreateObjCommand(interp_, name.c_str(),
          constructor_handler, static_cast(chb.get()), 0);

     constructors[interp_][name] = cb;
     call_policies[interp_][name] = p;
}


int tcl_cast::from(Tcl_Interp *interp, Tcl_Obj *obj)
{
     int res;
     int cc = Tcl_GetIntFromObj(interp, obj, &res);
     if (cc != TCL_OK)
     {
          throw tcl_error(interp);
     }

     return res;
}

long tcl_cast::from(Tcl_Interp *interp, Tcl_Obj *obj)
{
     long res;
     int cc = Tcl_GetLongFromObj(interp, obj, &res);
     if (cc != TCL_OK)
     {
          throw tcl_error(interp);
     }

     return res;
}

bool tcl_cast::from(Tcl_Interp *interp, Tcl_Obj *obj)
{
     int res;
     int cc = Tcl_GetBooleanFromObj(interp, obj, &res);
     if (cc != TCL_OK)
     {
          throw tcl_error(interp);
     }

     return res != 0;
}

double tcl_cast::from(Tcl_Interp *interp, Tcl_Obj *obj)
{
     double res;
     int cc = Tcl_GetDoubleFromObj(interp, obj, &res);
     if (cc != TCL_OK)
     {
          throw tcl_error(interp);
     }

     return res;
}

string tcl_cast::from(Tcl_Interp *interp, Tcl_Obj *obj)
{
     return Tcl_GetString(obj);
}

char const * tcl_cast::from(Tcl_Interp *interp, Tcl_Obj *obj)
{
     return Tcl_GetString(obj);
}

object tcl_cast::from(Tcl_Interp *interp, Tcl_Obj *obj)
{
     object o(obj);
     o.set_interp(interp);

     return o;
}
```

How do I resolve this?

Thanks

Answer (score 7):

The code seems to refer to the regular std::exception, but the symbol gets mixed because of using both the boost and std namespaces. Maybe it's some difference between VC and gcc headers.

In any case, adding the following lines to the file solves this compiler error and another similar conflict with shared_ptr in VC2010 (at least for me):

```
#define shared_ptr boost::shared_ptr
#define exception std::exception
```

Regards,
Miguel

Answer (score 1):

A project has been started to fix the problems in this library here: https://github.com/wsong83/cpptcl

Answer (score 0):

I notice `cpptcl.cc` has the following:

```
 try
 {
      iti->second->invoke(interp, objc, objv, pol);

      post_process_policies(interp, pol, objv, false);
 }
 catch (boost::exception const &e)
 {
      Tcl_SetResult(interp, const_cast(e.what()), TCL_VOLATILE);
      return TCL_ERROR;
 }
```

The compiler complains that `boost::exception`doesn't have `what()` (which indeed it doesn't since that's in `std::exception`). So you have to change this to use `get_error_info()`.

Also, I notice that the `const_cast` isn't taking a template argument. This is going to be problematic.